# Json Coast to Coast Play framework : Serializing Joda DateTime

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, scala-2.10, reactivemongo

Hi all I am new to play framework, if someone knows of a better approach then mentioned below please let me know.

So I have a model  and Reads/Writes/Format for it

```
case class Schedule (startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime)


object ScheduleSerializers {


  val userDateFormatter = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
  val nonImplicitUserFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  implicit val jodaDateTimeReads = Reads.jodaDateReads(userDateFormatter)
  implicit val jodaDateTimeWrites = Writes.jodaDateWrites(userDateFormatter)

  implicit val readSchedule: Reads[Schedule] = (
    (__ \ "startDate").read[String].map[DateTime](dt => DateTime.parse(dt, nonImplicitUserFormatter)) and
      (__ \ "endDate").read[String].map[DateTime](dt => DateTime.parse(dt, nonImplicitUserFormatter))
    )(Schedule)

  implicit val writeSchedule: Writes[Schedule] = (
    (__ \ "startDate").write[String].contramap[DateTime](dt => nonImplicitUserFormatter.print(dt)) and
      (__ \ "endDate").write[String].contramap[DateTime](dt => nonImplicitUserFormatter.print(dt))
    )(unlift(Schedule.unapply))

  implicit val formatSchdule = Format(readSchedule, writeSchedule)

}
```

Now I open the play console and do this

```
val sch = Json.parse(""" {
     | 
     |   "schedule" : { "starDate" : "04/02/2011 20:27:05" , "endDate" : "04/02/2011 20:27:05" }
     | }
     | """)
sch: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"schedule":{"starDate":"04/02/2011 20:27:05","endDate":"04/02/2011 20:27:05"}}

sch.validate[Schedule]
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.experiment.Schedule] = JsError(List((/endDate,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray()))), (/startDate,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))
```

I am getting an Error, but if I try to parse a single date for ex:

```
scala> val singleDate = Json.parse(""" "04/02/2011 20:27:05" """)
singleDate: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "04/02/2011 20:27:05"

singleDate.validate[DateTime]
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[org.joda.time.DateTime] = JsSuccess(2011-02-04T20:27:05.000-08:00,)
```

I am confused as to why 'singleDate' works but the validation on the 'Schedule' model fails. 
Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it because the path doesn't match? You would need to have something like `(__ \ "schedule" \ "startDate").read[String]`... in your Reads object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is rather clear: "path missing".

Instead of:

```
 (__ \ "startDate") ...
 (__ \ "endDate") ...
```

You have to give the real path:

```
 (__ \ "schedule" \ "startDate") ...
 (__ \ "schedule" \ "endDate") ...
```

By the way, as you define `jodaDateTimeReads` as `implicit`, you don't need to do the pasing by hand. And as you reads and writes are doing the same, just go with `Format`.

That should be enough:

```
implicit val formatSchedule: Format[Schedule] = (
  (__ \ "startDate").read[DateTime] and
  (__ \ "endDate").read[DateTime]
)(Schedule.apply, unlift(Schedule.unapply)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
implicit val dateWrites = jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
implicit val dateReads = jodaDateReads("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.scala#L411

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L645